# How to dispatch non blocking

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

I am having an issue that my UI is blocked for a second during execution of a saga. I have tried to make my saga non blocking and it looks like it is. It finishes very fast. Why is my dispatch blocking until the saga has finished?

```
//Saga
function* test(action) {
  console.time('test')
  yield put({type : 'test'});
  console.timeEnd('test')
}

function* changeFilterSaga(action) {
  console.time('changeFilterSaga')
  yield* test(test, action);
  console.timeEnd('changeFilterSaga')
}

export default function* watchChangeFilter() {
  yield takeLatest(FILTER_MYNDIGHET, changeFilterSaga);
}


//dispatch action
filterData: ({ apply, filter }) => {
  console.time('filterData')
  dispatch(changeFilter({ apply, filter }));
  console.timeEnd('filterData') // everything blocks until I am here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call `yield* test(test, action);` is actually blocking. It's the same as `yield call(test, action)`. In order to make this call non-blocking you need to fork it: `yield fork(test, action)`.